# SQL Query Help - Construction and process of calculations

Tags: sql

Here's the question :

I have 2 tables , one containing the base data and one containing data related to the base data with only one value so :

TABLE1
`pKey | category1 | category2 | ..3 |etc`

TABLE2
`pKey | value1 |`

Where `pKey` is unique to each real-world object, a serial number for example.

now, *how would I compare the tables to match the values with the objects in the other table with the aim of adding the values of the objects to the "owner" of the objects ?*

SCENARIO :

Obj1 is one of many franchises that one guy owns, at the end of the month we get a report stating the expenses/sales etc for all the franchises and all the owners of thereof of the brand and have to calculate how this particular owner did . So we compare the table2 to table1,to get the owner and add up the "nett profit" for this particular franchise to his running total at the end of the day hoping for data that looks like :

Table3 
`owner | Total Earnings |`

I've written a query that does the compare :
`SELECT * FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 WHERE Table1.pkey = Table2.pKey`

The only problem is that that, in itself, isn't very useful. So is the following process the way of doing this, disregarding syntax errors and me forgetting to press shift all the time :

`SELECT DISTINCT(Owner) FROM TABLE1`

then loop through Table1 for each owner to get all his pKeys

`SELECT pKey FROM Table1 Where Owner = ownerResult.Owner`

then compare the results from that to TABLE2 to get the Values

`SELECT Value FROM TABLE2 INNER JOIN TABLE1 WHERE table2.pKey = table1.pKey`

then do the additions on that result.

Also, does SQL handle floating point numbers, if so are there any special steps I should be taking?

Comment: lets say there are 20 owners, it'll have to loop through there for each one, it's clumsy and I don't like it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this all in one statement:

```
select
    t1.Owner,
    sum(t2.Value) as NetProfit
from
    Table1 t1
    inner join Table2 t2 on
        t1.pKey = t2.pKey
group by
    t1.Owner
```

What we're using here are called "aggregate functions." In this case, it's `sum`, but it could be `max` or `min` or `avg` or whatever. Furthermore, we can partition this by using the `group by` statement, to say, "I only want the aggregates to work at each distinct level of these columns." In this case, `owner`.

And to answer your last question, yes, it does. `double`, `decimal`, and `numeric` are all data types that can handle decimal numbers (there are quite a few more, too), but I need to know your type of database server (e.g.-MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle) to answer it more completely. Some even contain a `money` or `currency` data type, which ensures you don't have partial cents and what have you.

Comment: it's SQL Server, thanks loads for the quick answer btw, I'll test it in a second.

Comment: @Dani - If it's SQL Server, then check here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848794.aspx Those are all the available numeric data types. You'll want to look into `money` for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the sum of all values from table2:

```
Select t1.pkey, sum(t2.value) 
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t1.pkey = t2.pkey
group by t1.pkey
```

This will return only rows from table1 with at least one matching row in table2; if you want all rows from table1, use an outer join instead:

```
Select t1.pkey, sum(t2.value) 
from table1 t1
left outer join table2 t2 on t1.pkey = t2.pkey
group by t1.pkey
```

One remark regarding floating point values in SQL: if you want to handle currency amounts, **DO NOT USE FLOATING POINT ARITHMETIC FOR THIS**; use a fixed-point representation instead.
Otherwise, you'll run into rounding errors.